# adding event listener to stop a sound, when entering new scene

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, event-listener

I am making a game in FlashPro, with three scenes. 1st scene is the "press play scene", scene 2 is the playing scene and scene 3 will be the "game over scene".

I am trying to write the code to stop a sound playing in scene 1 of my game when entering scene 2.
The code to play the sound is this:

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.events.Event;


var mySound:Sound = new mainMusic();
var mySoundChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
mySoundChannel = mySound.play();
```

Now, I am very new to coding in general. Most examples I have found talk about stoping the sound with the click of a button. In my case, there will never be a Mouse, so I am trying to make an Event Listener that stops the sound when entering the new scene, or when a condition will be true.
I appreciate all help.

Comment: Executing **mySoundChannel.stop();** is enough. If you put it into the frame, the sound will stop playing as soon as playhead enters that frame.

Comment: @Organis Provided the variable would be visible in that part of code. OP's coding style looks like timeline coding which has visibility problems.

Comment: @Vesper Variables, declared on timeline, is visible everywhere on the same timeline. In the case of main timeline they will be visible and accessible even on another scene. Just checked it.

Comment: @Organis yess it stops! I guess if I want a new sound to start right after that, I can make a new var Sound with the new music in it and then start a new SoundChannel?

Comment: Sure. It's not like you're stopping all the sounds forever. If you want to play the same music over, just re-use it with **var anotherChannel:SoundChannel = mySound.play();** If it is another audio track, you need to create a separate **Sound** object.